# Python Segmentation fault: 11 on OSX

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault

Im starting development with python, and tried some simple commands like calculations.

But, some times python aborts with "Segmentation fault:11"
In google i didnt find a similar issue or solution for that.

Python is installed with homebrew.
home-brew doctor command don't show any issues for the python installation and is up to date.

Have anyone an Idea how to fix this ?

Here is the OSX Crash Log: http://pastebin.com/rKpPJKxJ

Comment: I'm in Mavericks and am having the same issue with Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 19):

Hmmm... spread the word. The following seems that it fixed it:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3 
cd ./lib/python3.3/lib-dynload 
sudo mv readline.so readline.so.disabled
```

Comment: Worked for me! Maybe obvious but just remember to use YOUR version of Python and not necessarily 3.3 if that's not what you have installed. I'm running 2.7 and this fix worked for me as well

Comment: If you're using Homebrew, do this in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/ (for example for 2.7.5)

Comment: Did this with a pythonbrew install and it's made command navigation impossible. Ie, ctrl+a, ctrl+e, arrow keys, all print garbage.

Comment: There's a better fix from another SO q to not break navigation, using a python patch script: http://bugs.python.org/issue18458#msg201087

Comment: Does not work for me in case of OS Yosemite. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in the python interpreter related to readline compatibility that has been fixed in the most recent candidates that were cut this weekend.

http://python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/

http://python.org/download/releases/3.3.3/

The issue, quoting from Ned Deily, writing on the [python-dev email list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-October/129832.html):

> On Tuesday, Apple released OS X 10.9 (a.k.a. Mavericks).   There has already 
>   been a lot of interest in it, in part because Apple has made it available for 
>   free and has made it easy for users with 10.8, 10.7, and (most) 10.6 systems 
>   to upgrade directly to 10.9.  Unfortunately, there are issues with our current 
>   maintenance releases (3.3.2 and 2.7.5) on OS X 10.9 that call for new 
>   maintenance releases as soon as possible.
>
> One is critical in that it causes the interpreter to crash when running in 
>   interactive mode (http://bugs.python.org/issue18458).  The problem was due to 
>   a long-standing compatibility issue in libedit's readline compatibility layer 
>   that upstream has finally fixed and Apple has now shipped in 10.9.  Because 
>   the python.org installers dynamically link to libedit, the original workaround 
>   in readline.c for the original design flaw in history indexing now causes a 
>   segfault on 10.9 when the user types in the second command interactively.  Not 
>   good.  Ronald devised a fix that allows readline.so at runtime to detect and 
>   work with either version of libedit so that we continue to have binary 
>   compatibility across multiple OS X releases.  That fix is already out in the 
>   3.4.0 alphas and backported to the 3.3 and 2.7 branches, awaiting release 
>   there.  Just in the last 12 hours, there have been at least four duplicates of 
>   the issue reported by users.  I've updated the original issue to explicitly 
>   mention 10.9, now that it is no longer under NDA, and to provide a 
>   downloadable script for inexperienced users to workaround the problem by 
>   "removing" readline.so.  Presumably, as word gets out, there will be fewer 
>   duplicate issues opened but the impact will remain.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue on El Capitan when I installed Homebrew and had to adjust my PATH variable to put `/usr/local/bin` up front. Python version in there was 2.7.3. Python in `/usr/bin` is 2.7.10. Removing the python symlink in `/usr/local/bin/` did the trick.