# Debugging Python crash on OS Sierra 10: "segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I need help debugging a python crash. Python is crashing and leaves the message `segmentation fault: 11` either when I run each line of code where it's meant to plot or when I run the entire script in the command line. I'm on a Mac running Sierra 10.12.4.

I am using python 2.7 but also have python 3.6 which I installed with homebrew. Homebrew is up to date.

Here's the crash log: https://pastebin.com/z8giGADs.

I have seen other stack overflow questions on this, such as: [Python Segmentation fault: 11 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768967/python-segmentation-fault-11-on-osx#19551329) but for example in one of the answers that recommends: `cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3` and then altering a file, I don't have the directory `Frameworks`. Any leads highly appreciated!!

Comment: OSX comes with python2.7 by default. There's a good chance your homebrew version and the default version in `/usr/bin/python` are screwing with each other.

Comment: I misspoke. I actually use the default python2.7 but installed 3.6 using home-brew. The script I am trying to run uses python 2.7. Is there other information I can supply that would help, @Shiva?

Comment: Besides uninstalling 3.6, I can't think of anything... apologies. :(